# "What new features of C# have you used?" vs "What new features of C# have you worked with?"

Tags: phrase-request, questions, phrase-choice

Does this question sound natural:

> What new features of C# have you used?

Or would you use another phrase, for example?

> What new features of C# have you worked with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, both sound perfectly fine. If I had to mark a difference between them, I would say that your second example sounds a *bit* more professional, like a question being proposed in an interview. Also, there is a mild difference in natural answers:

> "What new features of C# have you used?"

In this case, you could honestly answer this question with any feature you have used *once*, although this may not be the intent of the question. Rather,

> "What new features of C# have you worked with?"

This one seems to implicitly ask for features that you have used multiple times, features that you have a deeper understanding of and experience with. If you answer this with a feature you've only briefly used once, it may be construed as misleading.